# JSP page posting form even though it shouldn't - validation error?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am having some trouble with form validation on my JSP-pages. I've tried with both JavaScript and HTML5 validation. The HTML5 validation (required tag) works when viewing from a browser, but doesn't work in eclipse. The Javascript validation doesn't work - it does show the alert window, but is still posting to the database.

Servlet code (Only //CREATE CUSTOMER that's relevant)

```
  package g24.isp.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import g24.isp.ejb.Cabin;
import g24.isp.ejb.Customer;
import g24.isp.ejb.Hotel;
import g24.isp.ejb.Reservation;
import g24.isp.facade.Facade;
import g24.isp.facade.FacadeLocal;
import g24.isp.ejb.MethodClass;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HotelServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HotelServlet")
public class HotelServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private FacadeLocal facade;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HotelServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("MainServlet-doGet");
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = null;
        // Get hidden field
        String operation = request.getParameter("operation");

        if (operation.equals("showperson")) {
            System.out.println("MainServlet-show reservation");

            MethodClass mc = new MethodClass();
            String cNoString = request.getParameter("cabinTxt");
            int cNo = mc.ParseStringToInt(cNoString);

            if (cNo == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("Du måste mata in en siffra");
                url = "/Index.jsp";
            }

            else {
                Cabin c = facade.findByCabinNo(cNo);
                if (c != null) {
                    request.setAttribute("cabin", c);
                    url = "/Admin.jsp";
                }

                else {
                    url = "/Index.jsp";
                }

            }

            // SEARCH PERSON
        } else if (operation.equals("searchperson")) {
            System.out.println("MainServlet-searchperson");
            url = "/Index.jsp";
        }

        else if (operation.equals("createcustomer")) {

            String cPnr = request.getParameter("txtcPnr");
            String cAddress = request.getParameter("txtcAddress");
            String cPhone = request.getParameter("txtcPhone");
            String cName = request.getParameter("txtcName");

            if (cPnr != null && !"".equals(cPnr)) {
                System.out.println("Entering if-statement");
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setcPnr(cPnr);
                customer.setcAddress(cAddress);
                customer.setcPhone(cPhone);
                customer.setcName(cName);

                request.setAttribute("customer", customer);

                url = "/Index.jsp";
                System.out.println(url);
                facade.createCustomer(customer);
                System.out.println("Customer created");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(url);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

CreaterCustomer.JSP - page:

```
<%@ page import = "g24.isp.ejb.Customer" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="hogerbox">
        <h1></h1>
        <h2>Add Customer</h2>
        <p>
            <span class="boldtext">
                <form action="/HotelClient/HotelServlet" name="custForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                    <p>Customer pnr:</p>
                    <input style="width: 223px;" type="text" name="txtcPnr" required>
                    <p>First Name:</p>
                    <input style="width: 223px;" type="text" name="txtcName" required>
                    <p>Phone Nbr:</p>
                    <input style="width: 223px;" type="text" name="txtcPhone">
                    <p>Address:</p>
                    <input style="width: 223px;" type="text" name="txtcAddress">
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Customer">
                        <input name="operation" value="createcustomer" type="hidden">
                </form>
        </p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS-function

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.custForm.txtcPnr.value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        document.getElementByName("txtcPnr").value = "Please enter a cPnr"
        return false;
    }
 }
```

The JS nor HTML5 doesn't work in Eclipse, so we tried to do a workaround in the servlet. But it doesn't print out the "Entering if-statement" but still creates the customer. So clueless here, so some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If there is an error within the JavaScript file then the script is aborted and the page is submitted. Use the browser debugger (F12) and single step through the code to find the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [HTML5 doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5). That looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...and you can probably just forego the JavaScript validation and let HTML5 do the work for you.